# Can another Rest/gRPC service call a gRPC service?

Tags: rest, grpc

I am a newbie to GRPC, and trying to implement a GRPC service in C#. I wanted to know, if it possible for any other REST/GPRC service to call my service(although I think this should definitely be possible). If so, will only sharing the service client work, like in a normal REST service?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely have multiple services call your gRPC service, whether the calling service is rest or not.

I have an order-entry gRPC service that calls a cashier gRPC service, so I must inject a cashier client (the 'stub') into my order-entry service:

```
class OrderEntryServiceImpl @Inject constructor(private val kafkaProducer: KafkaProducer<String, ByteArray>,
                                            private val cashierStub: CashierGrpcKt.CashierCoroutineStub)
```

If the order-entry service were a rest service, I would inject the cashierStub in the same way.

My order-entry service then makes use of the cashier-service to lock a customer's funds:

```
override suspend fun submitOrder(request: OrderEntry.SubmitOrderRequest):
        SubmitOrderResponse {

    val responseBuilder = SubmitOrderResponse.newBuilder()
    val order = request.order
    if (!isOrderValid(order)) {
        return responseBuilder.setOrderSubmissionStatus(FAILURE_INVALID_ORDER).build()
    }
    when (order.orderType) {
        BUY, SELL -> {
            /**for new orders (not 'cancels' or 'modifies'), we need to post margin and generate
            an order id.**/
            val orderId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            val marginAmount = order.qtyOnMarket *
                    SATOSHIS_PER_CONTRACT * MAX_PRICE_OF_BINARY_OPTION
            val lockFundsResult = cashierStub.lockFunds(CashierRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setUserId("")
                    .setRelatedEntityId(orderId)
                    .setReason(TransactionReason.POST_MARGIN)
                    .setAmount(marginAmount).build())
...
```

One difference you may encounter has to do with how you test - if your service A calls service B using B's client, typically when testing service A you would mock service B's client to return responses applicable to the scenario under test. If service B is  gRPC however, you never mock the client 'stub' - instead you mock the base implementation of Service B itself, and use a 'real' stub to call it, likely over gRPC's inProcess channel builder which can be used to create embedded servers and channels for tests.  (This is true at least on JVM flavors of gRPC - not sure if you can mock a stub in c#)